Flex - item should take up only as much space as the text
I have a flex container and 2 items. The light-blue item has multiple spans. What I'd like to achieve is make the max-width of the light-blue item as big as the text spans. And the flex-item should also be as big as the text always wraps. I provide a code sandbox for testing. The screenshot shows that the light-blue container is way bigger than the text under specific viewport widths


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Align items vertically */
}

.flex-item {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  /* Allow items to shrink */
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Center items vertically */
}

.light-blue {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  /* Light blue background */
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Rounded corners */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* Align children horizontally */
  white-space: normal;
  /* Allow text to wrap */
}

.blue {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  /* Blue background */
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Rounded corners */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Optional styling for icon */

.icon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item light-blue">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="text">Termine sind frei verfügbar</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item blue">
    Termine anzeigen
  </div>
</div>





The wrapping of the text happens because of the width of the parent. Now if you want the parent to reduce the width because the child is wrapped that is not possible. The calculation of parent layout is already done. Now you can use min-content on the span which holds the text, but I don't think you want that because that will mean the text's parent width is same as the longest word in the text

Start by removing all those rules that you don't need. The flex items don't need display: inline-flex; (you almost never need inline-flex), nor do you need white-space: normal; (that's the default), and your colour classes should just set the colours, the border radius etc go on the .flex-item class.
Doing all that, we automatically get the correct behaviour:


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  .flex-item {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    .icon {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    /* "fake" a span that's too small */
    span.text {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }
}

.light-blue {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: white;
}
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item light-blue">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="text">Termine sind frei verfügbar</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item blue">
    Termine anzeigen
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item light-blue">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="text" style="width: 6em;">Termine sind frei verfügbar</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item blue">
    Termine anzeigen
  </div>
</div>




The problem with this implementation is that the text never stays into 1 line. So the text should be able to be in 1 line if there is enough space. But if not the text should wrap and the flex-item should apply it's children width

You can't get text to wrap and keep things "on one line". Those are mutually exclusive. Once the text wraps, it's on two lines, and as you can see the flex item shrinks so that there's no superfluous whitespace to the right. I've updated the post so you can see both situations in the same snippet.

I think there is a misunderstanding. So basically the text should always be able to wrap. It's just if there is enough space the text should also be displayed in 1 line. This is not mutually exclusive. The difficulty that I have is that the light blue flex-item should always have the same width of the text. Without huge whitespace to the right in some conditions.

I'm not sure that makes much sense: it would make far more sense to set the text inside your flex items to white-space: nowrap and then switch the flex direction so that your flex-items are below instead of next to each other when the screen gets too small (basically the standard responsive design approach)
